# Change default Magento 2 theme to use a boxed layout instead of full width?

Tags: layout, theme, template, css, less

Change default Magento 2 theme to use a boxed layout instead of full width?

I'd like to change my Magento 2 theme to use a boxed layout instead of a full layout. I've already started customizing the theme by creating a directory in:

```
app/design/frontend/<Company_Name>/<Theme_name>/
```

And been customizing various areas using:

```
app/design/frontend/<Company_Name>/<Theme_name>/Magento_Catalog/

app/design/frontend/<Company_Name>/<Theme_name>/Magento_Theme/

app/design/frontend/<Company_Name>/<Theme_name>/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_module.less
```

Etc, etc.

But, I've found that the site's layout itself is using a full width layout and I'd like to change that to a boxed layout. The theme's theme.xml is using the `Magento/blank` theme as a parent, also. `<parent>Magento/blank</parent>`

So basically just starting from scratch and wondering how I'd customize this theme to use a boxed layout.

Thank you.

Comment: When i'm inspecting both the luma and blank theme, they both have a max width set on the main container with `.page-main {max-width: 1280px;}`, so i'm not 100% sure what you mean when you say full width and boxed. Are you looking to have the header and the footer also be inside this container?

Comment: @circlesix Odd, what I'm seeing is that the `.page-wrapper` is using a `display:flex` element, and a `flex-direction:column` element as well, then the page is broken down into `page-header`, `nav-sections`, `page-main`, and `page-footer`. The custom theme I'm using uses Magento/blank as the parent.